# Как работает onmouseover в html тэгах?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Делаю статическую страницу ошибки, вставляю в текст ссылку :

`<a style="text-decoration:none;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration=underline" href="http...../">www.home.org</a>` не работает.

Хотел вставить  в начале в тэги `<style> a:hover {text-decoration: underline;} </style>` так тоже не работает. Как так?

---

1. `onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration="underline""`
2. `onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'"`
3. `onmouseover='this.style.textDecoration="underline"'`

а какой вариант должен быть?

---

рабочий второй вариант. Только  underline остаётся когда курсор уводишь, ну полгяжу, покапаюсь ) всем спасибо))

Comment: стоит посмотреть какую ошибку пишет консоль браузера. Судя по всему забыты кавычки вокруг _underline_

Comment: `onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" `, либо `onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration=\"underline\"" `

Comment: @SLy_huh, либо как третий вариант в ответе

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном коде нет кавычек вокруг *underline*, поэтому в момент выполнения будет искаться переменная с таким именем, и если ее нет, будет соответствующая ошибка.

Для исправления достаточно обрамить все кавычками, например так:

```
onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'"
```

Так как этот обработчик отвечает только за ситуацию, когда курсор находится *над* элементом, при уходе курсора, никакой код не выполняется и стиль остается тем, который был присвоен:

```
text-decoration: underline
```

Для решения, можно использовать события [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseout), [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)

Лучшее решение, не использовать для цели указанной в вопросе скрипты, а использовать css.

Почему не сработал вариант со стилем в вопросе?

Потому что Inline-style, имеют более высокий приоритет, и

```
style="text-decoration:none;"
```

Просто всегда перебивал стиль указанный в теге `style`.

Для решения, можно убрать inline-style, и добавить правило в tag:

```css
a { text-decoration:none; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```